# Hebrew in title breaks tweet

Tags: bug, status-norepro, twitter, hebrew

I'm not sure if this is an SE bug, or a Twitter bug, but the fact remains...when [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48598/do-sociopaths-psychopaths-lack-%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA-of-good-and-evil?atw=1) was [tweeted](https://twitter.com/StackJudaism/status/536366981541548032) earlier, it showed up on my phone in three pieces, missing the Hebrew.

Reason for suggesting that this is a SE bug rather than a Twitter bug: previous tweets with Hebrew in them show up as question marks.

Reason for suggestion that this is a Twitter bug: previous SE tweets have shown Hebrew characters as question marks.

( *I am getting these tweets as text messages to my basic phone* )

Comment: Nothing is broken for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eQbu2.png so it's likely a problem with your phone, maybe it does not have Hebrew font installed on it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It doesn't, and usually renders Hebrew text as question marks....in the end, you and Scimonster are likely right; it's probably not a SE problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

It appears to be an issue with your phone. Viewing it online (from my computer), the Hebrew shows up just fine.

([Image from @ShadowWizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQbu2.png))

Comment: You're right -- it's likely either a phone bug or a Twitter bug, since it shows up normally on the computer. Answer accepted.